# Value of JButtons always fits within button in Windows but not in Linux

Tags: java, linux, windows, user-interface, jbutton

So I have a few JButtons in a Java program I've written which obviously contain a value (as in the text which appears on the button).

When I run the application in Windows, this text always fits inside the JButton - no matter how small I make the window (I have set a minimum size for the window). However, when I run the application in Linux, the text does not seem to fit inside the buttons.

I am defining my JButtons like this:

```
public class ButtonPanel extends JPanel {

private JButton undoButton;

/**
 * Button panel constructor.
 */
public ButtonPanel() {
    // Set the layout
    this.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 10, 5));

    // Add all buttons and register their listeners
    undoButton = new JButton("Undo");
    undoButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 50));
    undoButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                                        System.out.println("Undo button pressed");
                                        try {
                                            App.performActivity(Activity.UNDO);
                                        } catch (Exception e1) {
                                            e1.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
    this.add(undoButton);
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thank you,

Callum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
undoButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 50));
```

Get rid of that statement!!!

Don't hard code the preferred size of a component. Each component will determined its preferred size and the layout manager will use this information to position the components on the panel.